# Problem with OnClick event and programmatically added table rows. [Edited]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

**Preface:** I've got a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table on my ASPx page that I define within the aspx page itself and it contains numerous entry fields (textbox, etc). It has a DropDownList that based on what is selected will programmatically add more rows just above the footer of the table. The footer of this table has a save button that once clicked will activate the OnClick event. I then loop through my rows in the table and save the input information

**Issue:** The issue i am running into is that when I go to loop through the rows of the table, the programmatically added rows are no where to be found. I've stepped through each control of each cell of each row, and it goes from the last row that was defined on the aspx page to the footer. I'm guess this is something I completely botched, because I was completely unable to find anyone else having the same problem via Google, and I pride myself on being a pretty good googler.

**Note:** Table is probably too big to post here, but i can post portions if needed.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

**Edit:** This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIvUo.jpg

The rows are being added with codebehind, so once a user selects the item from the dropdownlist then I add the rows with the codebehind.

**Solution:** Needed to re-add the programmatically generated rows during my page_load.

Comment: What technique are you using to 'programmatically add more rows'? (Are you using javaScript, or code behind?)

Comment: Use a GridView instead. Otherwise recreate all rows on postback and store the count of already created rows in ViewState.

Comment: @Dexter the rows are being added with codebehind.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The reason I am not using a gridview is because the number of added rows will vary. Essentially i am making a request system that will have numerous steps. Any number of steps might be a step to request access to something, and based on the number of steps needing to ask for access i give the users the new rows where they will enter how long the person needs access, and what not (shown in picture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From code-behind, dynamically added rows are not persisted across postbacks.  You have to re-add the rows during Init/PreInit.  Once added back, viewstate will be loaded between init/load for these rows.

HTH.

Comment: Perhaps this is where I messed up. When the button is clicked and the OnClick event is fired, does it not first go to that event before posting back?

Comment: This pointed out part of my flaw... the Page_Load event is gets done before the OnClick event. I'll have to look further and see if this completely fixes my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Well, this did the trick. Just had to recreate the rows in the Page_Load. Thanks a bunch!